# How to retrieve active Users of Marketing cloud using SOAP or REST API Call

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I tried using this SOAP referral code but no luck, can someone help me on this.

```
     <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
       <s:Header>
         <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
         <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:5dfca442-f1a0-4f7c-9419-8ace5658d2a3</a:MessageID>
         <a:ReplyTo>  <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
         </a:ReplyTo>
         <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
         <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-88b91f91-bac2-489b-90fb-37e7b256e20c-1">
               <o:Username>ABCD</o:Username>
               <o:Password>ABCD</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
         </o:Security>
       </s:Header>
       <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            <Properties>email</Properties>
            <Properties>ActiveFlag</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>isAPIUser</Properties>
            <Properties>UserID</Properties>
            <Properties>LastSuccessfulLogin</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
         </RetrieveRequestMsg>
       </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please share the response you are seeing when making that request.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via SOAP, WSProxy and an undocumented REST endpoint. Both SOAP and WSproxy will return some Role and Permission, where the REST API call will only return: id, memberId, userName, name, email, canImpersonate.

Below is the SOAP Envelope I use (Body only) when retrieveing this info:

```
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
        <Properties>AccountUserID</Properties>
        <Properties>ActiveFlag</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Email</Properties>
        <Properties>ID</Properties>
        <Properties>LastSuccessfulLogin</Properties>
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>Roles</Properties>
        <Properties>UserID</Properties>
        <Properties>UserPermissions</Properties>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Below is a WSProxy call I use:

```
 var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  if(mid) {
    // Set ClientID 
    prox.setClientId({ "ID": mid });
  }

  var cols = ["AccountUserID","ActiveFlag","CustomerKey","Email","ID","LastSuccessfulLogin","ModifiedDate","Name","Roles","UserID","UserPermissions"];

  var res = prox.retrieve("AccountUser", cols);
```

and finally below is the REST endpoint:

```
GET /platform/v1/accounts/{{MID}}/users
Host: https://{{subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: The soap request only returns the top level business unit results for me. Is there a way (with the soap call) to get the results for all business units (or for a business unit not the top level)?

Comment: Hi Gail,

You can add a parameter for querying all accounts with:
var QueryAllAccounts = true;

Then edit the request to:
var res = prox.retrieve("AccountUser", cols, null, QueryAllAccounts );